# How create a new bucket in Firebase Cloud Storage from Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I'm into a project which I need to update profile pictures to firebase users. Now we're using firebase auth to manage the users so I need to change de profile photo.

The problem is that I have not access to the firebase project by the web, so I need to create a firebase storage bucket from javascript to upload the images and save them.

I already have the credentials so I don't need to get it, no?

Is it possible to create a new bucket from javascript without logging into the firebase website?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js, you may build a new bucket in Firebase Cloud Storage from JavaScript without logging into the Firebase website.

You may follow these documentation references:

- [Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)
- [Firebase Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage)
- [Firebase Storage Buckets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start#using_multiple_storage_buckets)